# mysqli_fetch_row - using it as an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I was wondering that we have this function in PHP:

```
mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

and this returns a simple array, but using it as an array like

```
mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
```

to get the first element of the array doesn't work, so you have to create a new variable which will contain the returned array.

Could anyone explain why isn't this working?

Comment: This should work starting with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Thank you Gerald, you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because mysqli_fetch_row is a function that returns a value - it's not an array itself.

Assigning a variable will retrieve the result. Unfortunately that's how it works in earlier versions of PHP.

Gerald's link identifies the functionality it as availble in PHP 5.4, so I guess that you're using an earlier version.

Comment: This depends on the used PHP version, see the duplicate.

Comment: Just read it. Thanks Gerald - useful to know. Object derefencing is certainly a great feature and glad to see that it's there in 5.4.  I'll update my answer.